How can I insert an PDF as an Printout Com Object OneNote
so I have my Programm which creates Sections and Subsections based on Folder. Which works.
But I tried multiple things but I cant get the Inserting of an PDF to work in an created page. I also did not find anything in the documentation and the information is where sparse. I also tried oneNote API over Graph but the File Limits are an Problem. I tried multiple Approaches and put to many hours in.
public async Task AddPdfToPage(string sectionId, string notebookID,string pageName, string pdfPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(pdfPath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The specified PDF file does not exist.", pdfPath);
        }

        // Ensure the page exists or create it if it doesn't
        string pageId = EnsurePageExists(sectionId, pageName);

        //XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote";

        //// Generate unique IDs
        //string outlineId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //string currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ");
        //string author = "Your Name";
        //string authorInitials = "YN";

        //// Convert PDF pages to images
        //List<string> base64Images = ConvertPdfToImagesBase64(pdfPath);

        //// Create OEChildren element containing images
        //XElement oeChildren = new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
        //    base64Images.Select(base64Image =>
        //        new XElement(ns + "OE",
        //            new XAttribute("objectID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //            new XAttribute("creationTime", currentTime),
        //            new XAttribute("lastModifiedTime", currentTime),
        //            new XAttribute("author", author),
        //            new XAttribute("authorInitials", authorInitials),
        //            new XElement(ns + "Image",
        //                new XAttribute("objectID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //                new XAttribute("format", "png"),
        //                new XAttribute("isPrintout", "true"),
        //                new XElement(ns + "Data", base64Image)
        //            )
        //        )
        //    )
        //);

        //// Create the Outline element
        //XElement outlineElement = new XElement(ns + "Outline",
        //    new XAttribute("objectID", outlineId),
        //    new XAttribute("author", author),
        //    new XAttribute("authorInitials", authorInitials),
        //    new XAttribute("creationTime", currentTime),
        //    new XAttribute("lastModifiedTime", currentTime),
        //    oeChildren
        //);

        //// Create the Page element with the Page ID
        //XElement pageElement = new XElement(ns + "Page",
        //    new XAttribute("ID", pageId),
        //    outlineElement
        //);

        //// Convert to string
        //string updatedContent = pageElement.ToString();

        //// Update the page content
        //oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(updatedContent, DateTime.MinValue, XMLSchema.xs2013);

        string attachmentHtml = "<a href=\"" + pdfPath + "\">Download Attachment</a>";
        oneNoteApp.GetHierarchy(sectionId, HierarchyScope.hsPages, out string xml);
        oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(attachmentHtml, DateTime.MinValue);

        Log.Information("PDF file inserted into page {PageName} in section {SectionId}.", pageName, sectionId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred while inserting PDF into page: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
        if (ex is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comEx)
        {
            Log.Error("COM Error Code: {ErrorCode}", comEx.ErrorCode);
        }
        throw;
    }
}    public async Task AddPdfToPage(string sectionId, string notebookID,string pageName, string pdfPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(pdfPath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The specified PDF file does not exist.", pdfPath);
        }

        // Ensure the page exists or create it if it doesn't
        string pageId = EnsurePageExists(sectionId, pageName);

        //XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote";

        //// Generate unique IDs
        //string outlineId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //string currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ");
        //string author = "Your Name";
        //string authorInitials = "YN";

        //// Convert PDF pages to images
        //List<string> base64Images = ConvertPdfToImagesBase64(pdfPath);

        //// Create OEChildren element containing images
        //XElement oeChildren = new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
        //    base64Images.Select(base64Image =>
        //        new XElement(ns + "OE",
        //            new XAttribute("objectID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //            new XAttribute("creationTime", currentTime),
        //            new XAttribute("lastModifiedTime", currentTime),
        //            new XAttribute("author", author),
        //            new XAttribute("authorInitials", authorInitials),
        //            new XElement(ns + "Image",
        //                new XAttribute("objectID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //                new XAttribute("format", "png"),
        //                new XAttribute("isPrintout", "true"),
        //                new XElement(ns + "Data", base64Image)
        //            )
        //        )
        //    )
        //);

        //// Create the Outline element
        //XElement outlineElement = new XElement(ns + "Outline",
        //    new XAttribute("objectID", outlineId),
        //    new XAttribute("author", author),
        //    new XAttribute("authorInitials", authorInitials),
        //    new XAttribute("creationTime", currentTime),
        //    new XAttribute("lastModifiedTime", currentTime),
        //    oeChildren
        //);

        //// Create the Page element with the Page ID
        //XElement pageElement = new XElement(ns + "Page",
        //    new XAttribute("ID", pageId),
        //    outlineElement
        //);

        //// Convert to string
        //string updatedContent = pageElement.ToString();

        //// Update the page content
        //oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(updatedContent, DateTime.MinValue, XMLSchema.xs2013);

        string attachmentHtml = "<a href=\"" + pdfPath + "\">Download Attachment</a>";
        oneNoteApp.GetHierarchy(sectionId, HierarchyScope.hsPages, out string xml);
        oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(attachmentHtml, DateTime.MinValue);

        Log.Information("PDF file inserted into page {PageName} in section {SectionId}.", pageName, sectionId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred while inserting PDF into page: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
        if (ex is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comEx)
        {
            Log.Error("COM Error Code: {ErrorCode}", comEx.ErrorCode);
        }
        throw;
    }
}

